# 12.04 Dashboard's search opens program as text file rather than running as app

Tags: unity-dash

I have a program called df,which is in /home/isaac/df_linux, which I run this to play the game.

Running from here the dashboard search, found by pressing , will run df as a gedit text file.

If i put it in /home/isaac/.df_linux the dashboard wont even see the df file.

Is there a proper way for the dash to find and execute my game?

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a program called alacarte and added my program there. After a restart the ubuntu dashboard saw the new app. I can now run df form the 12.04 dash.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like the file isn't marked as executable. You can pop into the command line and use

```
chmod +x (file name)
```

or find the file in nautilus, right click, go to the permissions tab and check the "allow executing file as program" button.

EDIT: also ensure the correct shebang is present; try adding

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to the top of the file

Comment: It is, unfortunately.

Comment: what does the file do? is it a shell script? if it needs executing in some way, ensure it has the right shebang (#!/bin/bash for example)

Comment: `#!/bin/sh
DF_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
cd "${DF_DIR}"
export SDL_DISABLE_LOCK_KEYS=1 # Work around for bug in Debian/Ubuntu SDL patch.
#export SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED=1 # Centre the screen.  Messes up resizing.
./libs/Dwarf_Fortress $* # Go, go, go! :)`